# I got a exception. No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller, entitymanager

I'm using spring java jpa.
I got 'No transactional EntityManager available' exception.
I want to save member data in my database(oracle) but anything happens.

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="kr.co.myboard.domain" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="aa" />
    <property name="password" value="0000" />
</bean>
```

MemberService.java

```
@Service
public class MemberService {
@Autowired
private MemberDao memberDao;
public void join(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String pw = request.getParameter("pw");
    String nickname = request.getParameter("nickname");
    Member member = new Member();
    try {
        member.setId(id);
        member.setPw(BCrypt.hashpw(pw, BCrypt.gensalt(10)));
        member.setNickname(nickname);
        memberDao.join(member);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("fail to join : "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

MemberDao.java

```
@Repository
public class MemberDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void join(Member member) {
    em.persist(member);
}
}
```

other function ( find(), createQuery() work normally ) but persist isn't working. please give me an answer. ㅠㅠ

+++ pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyBoard</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyBoard</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>MyBoard</name>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version> 4.1.2.RELEASE </org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA, Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Common DBCP(Database Connection Pool) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>9</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following changes in `context.xml`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: I revise that but the same exception still occur